# In manifold theory, in what sense is the derivative a first-order approximation?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

As I move on from the calculus definition of the derivative to the differential geometric definition in terms of tangent spaces, I am wondering how to recover the notion that the derivative of a function represents the first order approximation.

Clearly the definitions of the derivative traffic in first order concepts: tangent vectors can be thought of equivalence classes of curves agreeing up to first order; [one characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_the_cotangent_space) of the tangent space at $x \in M$ is the dual space to $I/I^2$, where $I$ is the ideal of $C^\infty$ functions that vanish at $x$, and so on.

These definitions seem to be well-suited to a characterization of $Df$ as approximating $f$ up to first order at $x \in M$, but I am having trouble putting my finger on it and expressing it precisely.

I know that when we're in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the "approximation" property of the derivative works very well because we can identify the tangent space at a given point with $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself. But what about in the more general setting? In what sense do we have "approximation up to first order" there? What is it exactly that's agreeing with $f$ up to $o(\|h\|)$?

Comment: The concept that is precisely generalized is "linear approximation". Namely, the differential of a function induces uniquely a linear map between tangent vectors, which in familiar contexts is exactly the first order approximation.

Comment: I dont know if you thought about this a lot since you posted. But do you know how to think about the range and domain in this context? On a manifold we in some sense linearise these as well not only the function itself. The tangent space is not equal to the domain and range themselfs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to phrase this is in terms of Taylor's theorem for maps between Euclidean spaces, after some "chart-nonsense". Maybe you're looking for something not involving coordinates, in which case this answer may not be satisfying.

Let's say that $f: M^m \to N^n$ is a map between manifolds. Given a fixed "basepoint" $x \in M$, choose coordinate charts $(\phi, U)$, where $x \in U \subset M$, and $(\psi, V)$, where $f(x) \in V \subset N$. By this I mean that $\phi: U \to \phi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\psi: V \to \psi(V) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphisms to open sets in Euclidean spaces. For notation's sake, let $\tilde{f} = \psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U) \to \psi(V)$ be the map between Euclidean spaces corresponding to $f$ in our coordinates, and let $\tilde{x} = \phi(x) \in \phi(U) \subset{\mathbb{R}^m}$.

Taylor's theorem applied to $\tilde{f}$ says that
$$ \tilde{f}(\tilde{x} + h) = \tilde{f}(\tilde{x}) + D\tilde{f}_{\tilde{x}} \cdot h  + o(||h||).$$
Here $D\tilde{f}_{\tilde{x}}$ is the $n \times m$ matrix of partial derivatives of $\tilde{f}$ at $\tilde{x}$. We view $D\tilde{f}_{\tilde{x}}$ as a linear map $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$.
$D\tilde{f}_{\tilde{x}}$ is precisely the matrix for $Df_x: T_x M \to T_{f(x)} N$ in our chosen coordinates, which give us bases for the tangent spaces $T_x M$ and  $T_{f(x)} N$.

*Edit:* If our manifolds are endowed with Riemannian metrics, then the exponential map gives us a canonical way to identify a neighborhood of the origin in the tangent space $T_x M$ with a neighborhood of $x \in M$ (and similarly for $N$). Then Euclidean coordinates on $T_x M$ give us geodesic normal coordinates on $M$, and the above discussion of course applies in those coordinates. Radial distances (i.e., distances to $x$) are preserved under the exponential map. Thus, with the notation from above, $||h||$ is precisely the distance from $x$ to $\phi(\tilde{x} + h) = \text{exp}_x(h)$, and you can think of "$o$" as being measured in terms of distances on $N$. In this setting one should think that we are approximating $f(y)$ (for $y$ near $x$) by $f(x)$ plus a first-order correction, which is given precisely by applying the derivative $Df_x$ to a tangent vector $h$ that measures the deviation of $y$ from $x$ (modulo translating via $\text{exp}_x$ and $\text{exp}_{f(x)}$ between the manifolds and the tangent spaces, where "plus" makes sense).

Comment: That is helpful. But as you say, using charts may be less than satisfying if they distort greatly our notion of distances on the manifold (indeed what notion there may be is a question in itself...do we need a Riemannian manifold to talk about first order approx?), and so distort any interpretation of "first order approximation". Or maybe there is some sense in which charts preserve "first order approximation" that I am missing.

Comment: @Eric Auld: You're correct that distances only make sense in the presence of a Riemannian metric. I have edited my answer to comment on this. I hope it's helpful.